# detecting if a SWF file makes network calls

Tags: php, flash

Is there a way, upon upload (server side maybe?), to test/detect if a users flash file (SWF) uses any network operations or pulls in content dynamically? I'm trying to restrict users to only localized files and code in their SWF files.

I'm thinking along the lines of maybe a server side (linux) SWF Decompiler that i can search the Action-script of the SWF for any non-approved functions like loadMovie or ExternalInterface

Comment: Can you explain the use-case a little better, as well as what you're trying to achieve? It might help us understand the question and come up with a real solution.

Comment: Sure, I'm trying to allow users to upload an web ad, but I want to do some QA and reject any files that try to load in variables or files from other servers. (Which can be malicious in certain ad enviroments) I've seen this type of functionality on say, Google AdSense where you're allowed to use some simple animation in a flash file, but you can't load in a 5 min video. So they programmatically kickback your upload with an error about not allowing network operations.

Comment: Interesting idea. There's a couple of ways to do this. You could try blacklisting particular strings in the SWF file (e.g. network APIs and URLs), or you could try to find some sort of PHP-based SWF parser and build your logic from that.

Comment: You might consider forcing users to upload the source (.fla I think), parsing it, and compiling it an .swf on your end.  Compiling should be straightforward and less error-prone than decompiling.

Comment: Blacklisting certain functionality is never going to be 100% reliable, there will always be someone who finds something you missed. The only truly reliable way to do something like this is to create a virtual machine that can actually execute the SWF, but that probably falls beyond the scope of this site and certainly beyond the scope of my knowledge...

Comment: I've started down the decompiling path and found a cool tool that may help me in my quest. `swfdump` seems to give me all the actions / functions that are being called inside a SWF file. http://www.swftools.org/swfdump.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flash Movies and ActionScript - Stop the video from working offline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715052/flash-movies-and-actionscript-stop-the-video-from-working-offline)